# How to create a zip file without the middle directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip

I have a directory structure:

```
    20150626/B/CCType1/file1
    20150626/B/CCType2/file2
    20150626/B/CCType3/file3
```

In the Zip file I want the directory structure to be:

```
    20150626/CCType1/file1
    20150626/CCType2/file2
    20150626/CCType3/file3
```

Skipping directory B, without creating a new directory structure and copying/moving files explicitly as there are a large number of files!

Answer (score 0):

This trick using sym link should do the work and avoid copying/moving !

```
cd 20150626/
ln -s B 20150626
zip -r yourfile.zip 20150626/
```

(I am not sure you can use zip directly to do it)